# Topology Question on Connectedness

Tags: general-topology

I have no idea how to do this problem.  Any suggestion would be great

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. Suppose that $Y$ is connected,
and that $f^{-1}(y)$ is also connected, for each $y$ in $Y$.

(a) Show that if $f$ is a quotient map, then $X$ is connected.

(b) If $f$ is not a quotient map, must $X$ necessarily be connected?
Explain your answer.

Comment: @Tyler: Susan has said that she’s working on her own. You have no idea how many problems she’s managed to solve without coming here.

Comment: @Susan: Regardless of what you think of Tyler's flag, profanity and insults are absolutely inappropriate (as a moderator I can read your deleted comments). You deleted them quickly, which is appreciated, but any further incidents will be cause for a suspension.

Comment: I am going through tons of qualifying exam questions and don't know how to do all of them.

Comment: This is an alternative proof for (a). Since quotient spaces have a universal property and connectedness can be proven via a function, it is a promising idea to combine these concepts. Let $g:X\to\{0,1\}$ be a continuous map. $f(x)=f(z)$ implies $g(x)=g(z)$ since fibers are connected. So $g$ induces a continuous map $h:Y\to\{0,1\}$ such that $h\circ f=g$. But $h$ is constant since $Y$ is connected, so $g$ is constant, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, non-empty open sets whose union is $X$. For each $y\in Y$ let $F_y=f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, the *fibre* over $y$. Show that for each $y\in Y$, either $F_y\subseteq U$, or $F_y\subseteq V$. Then let $U'=\{y\in Y:F_y\subseteq U\}$ and $V\,'=\{y\in Y:F_y\subseteq V\}$, and use the fact that $f$ is a quotient map to show that $U'$ and $V\,'$ are open in $Y$.

(b) Let $Y=\Bbb R$, and let $\Bbb P=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. For any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb R$ let $$X_{A,B}=(\Bbb Q\times A)\cup(\Bbb P\times B)\;,$$ and let $f:X\to Y:\langle r,s\rangle\mapsto r$ be the projection to the first coordinate. Show how to choose $A$ and $B$ so that $f$ has connected fibres, but $X$ is not connected.